# display about me next to profile photo

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display about me next to profile photo. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <section class="col col-md-12">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <img height="100" src="/ui/img/male.png" class="profilePic">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <h1 class="ng-binding">Hi Test!</h1>
      <br>
      <h6>About</h6>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Both have pull-left class yet the about me is displayed below photo when viewed in screen 1920 * 1080. If I reduce the about me text to just `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,` it is viewed perfectly next to photo.

I want that the about me should be displayed next to photo in all conditions. If the resolution is lower it should keep displaying in new line and then under photo too (unlike table's td).

Please let me know what am I missing? I am not a HTML designer so have limited skills. I tried each combination of display like inline-block etc but they wouldn't work

**EDIT**

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4hLM/1/

**EDIT:**

Ideally this is how I want the HTML code should behave:

http://gyazo.com/50546b6d806148c0d3dc9f6f962e6a5d

Comment: Post your fiddle buddy.

Comment: posted the link buddy

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/  Post your code here along with the css u have used here and share the fiddle to let us see what is the current output.

Comment: There is no specify css. Bootstrap is already added. If you remove the rest of the css like profilePic it won't matter since it only has width set on it.

Comment: Can't tell what happens there, but if you remove the `<p>` block it works fine.

Comment: Exactly but I can't remove p as I have about me to be shown.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/r4hLM/10/ You just have to put them all in the same div and just float the image.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Exactly what I am looking for and I had this code but it doesn't work when text is small. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4hLM/12/. You're very close. Just need a fix for small text which I am unable to find!

Comment: OK...how about this..http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/r4hLM/30/ It does assume a fixed image size though.

Comment: Hmm, yes :). However Tushar already answered as the only thing to remove is float: left of class="name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left` of `class="name"`

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r4hLM/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution http://jsfiddle.net/r4hLM/2/

CSS added:

```
.width20{
      width:20% !important;
}
.width80{
      width:79% !important;
    margin-left:1% !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="col col-md-12">
        <div class="pull-left width20">
            <img height="100" src="/ui/img/male.png" class="profilePic" />
        </div>
        <div class="name width80" style="float:left;">
             <h1 class="ng-binding">Hi Test!</h1>

            <br/>
             <h6>About</h6>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry that is not what I am looking after. In your example, h1 should be displayed next to photo as it in same level with image but About and lorem ipsum should run in and start below the image. I want a fluid layout. Does that make sense? If not I can post a picture to show how it should look visually.

Comment: Also I don't want a width:80%. My profilePic is fixed of width: 100px;

Comment: Bhaijaan can you post it here. Actually i am on an intranet with limited access and the link that you gave is not accessible here.